# How to exclude a field from spellcheck in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, spell-checking

I have a `SharePointWebControls:UserField` in a page layout that needs to be excluded from spell checking, as otherwise whenever a user is selected there are a large number of spelling errors are detected in the code-behind for the control.

It seems that in Sharepoint 2007 this behaviour could be implemented by using `excludefromspellcheck = "true"` but this doesn't seem to work for Sharepoint 2010. Has anyone come across the same problem and found a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on SpellCheckEntirePage.js, that appears to still be the way:

```
var elements=document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (index=0; index < elements.length;++index)
{
    if (null !=elements[index].getAttribute("excludeFromSpellCheck"))
    {
        continue;
    }
    // snipped - if (elements[index].tagName=="INPUT")
    // snipped - else if (elements[index].tagName=="TEXTAREA")
}
```

But excludeFromSpellCheck is not a property of [UserField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.userfield_properties.aspx), so it probably won't automatically copy down to the rendered HTML. When rendered, the UserField control is made up of several elements. I would try looking at the View Source to see if excludeFromSpellCheck is making it into the final HTML. But to set the attribute on the appropriate elements, you might need to use some jQuery like this:

```
$("(input|textarea)[id*='UserField']").attr("excludeFromSpellCheck", "true");
```

Comment: Took a bit more poking to get normal javascript to do the job instead of using jQuery, but this approach worked to set the attribute on all of the rendered html elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the spell check for certain fields by setting the "excludeContentFromSpellCheck" attribute to "true" on text area and input controls that you dont want to be spell checked.

I did this on all my page layouts. Now i dont get false positives anymore.

The solution is to add a div tag around the fields you don't want spell checked and adding a javascript that sets "excludeFromSpellCheck" to "true" for the elements within the div tag.

The solution i found is described here: [Inaccurate Spell Check on SharePoint Publishing Pages](http://blog.cube4.com.au/?p=1016)

Answer (score 0):

Joe Furner posted this solution, which has worked for me.
https://www.altamiracorp.com/blog/employee-posts/spell-checking-your-custom-lay

It excludes all PeoplePickers on the page:

```
function disableSpellCheckOnPeoplePickers() {
    var elements = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {
        if (elements[index].tagName == "INPUT" && elements[index].parentNode && elements[index].parentNode.tagName == "SPAN") {
            var elem = elements[index];
            if (elem.parentNode.getAttribute("NoMatchesText") != "") {
                disableSpellCheckOnPeoplePickersAllChildren(elem.parentNode);
            }
        }
    }
}

function disableSpellCheckOnPeoplePickersAllChildren(elem) {
    try {
        elem.setAttribute("excludeFromSpellCheck", "true");
        for (var i = 0; i < elem.childNodes.length; i++) {
            disableSpellCheckOnPeoplePickersAllChildren(elem.childNodes[i]);
        }
    } 
    catch(e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is  working partially only,because if you put the people picker value again checking the people picker garbage value for one time.